# How to programmatically produce a video on the iPad platform?

Tags: iphone, ipad, video

I would like to programmatically produce a video using the microphone on the iPad (for sound) and the screen display (for visual)?  Is this possible?  How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but not easy. A rough outline:

1. Start capturing the audio: [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)
2. Capture individual images of the screen as fast as you can: [How to capture current view screenshot and reuse in code? (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879064/how-to-capture-current-view-screenshot-and-reuse-in-code-iphone-sdk)
3. Later, combine the two into a video. I have no clue how to do this part.