# iPhone/iPad question how to show dialog + how to make screenshot of screen?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, dialog, screenshot

I need to show dialog in my iPhone/iPad app (kind of like in Photos, left bottom button which opens dialog with choices "Email Photo", "MMS", "Assign to Contact", "Use a Wallpaper", etc...) -- is it possible? How this view element is called?

And the second questions - is somewhat related. One of the options would be "Email Current Screen", which needs to make screenshot of current screen (obviously without this dialog :-) and open in email to send an email. Please suggest how can I make screenshot? I force it to attach to the email? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question: it's called an action sheet, and is represented by the `UIActionSheet` class. On the iPhone, you can display it in your view using its `-showInView:` method; on the iPad, you can display it from a toolbar button with the `-showFromBarButtonItem:animated:` method, or from an arbitrary rectangle in a view with `-showFromRect:inView:animated:`. Note that since these are two separate code paths, you'll want to use the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` macro (Google it) to determine what type of device your code's running on.

Answer (score 0):

here is the question which deals with taking the screen shot

[How to capture current view screenshot and reuse in code? (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879064/how-to-capture-current-view-screenshot-and-reuse-in-code-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, in MonoTouch (.NET):

```
    public class ScreenShot
{
    public static UIImage TakeScreenShot (UIView view)
    {
        RectangleF canvasRect = view.Bounds;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (canvasRect.Size);

        CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
        ctx.FillRect (canvasRect);
        view.Layer.RenderInContext (ctx);

        UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();

        UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

        return newImage;
    }
}
```