# iOS : UIView blurring things moving behind it

Tags: ios, uiview, effect

I'm wondering if it's possible to blur everything behind a view... Those things are expected to move.

Example: I have an UIViewcontroller containing an UITableView, and a small UIView over it, wich can be moved with touch. I want this view to be transparent but blurring anything behind it, to achieve an effect similar to this one : 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/rtaGlassEffectLib/rtaGlassEffect.png

So... possible or not ?

Answer (score 3):

If things are not changing behind the view you can take a screenshot (See this question: [How to capture current view screenshot and reuse in code? (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879064/how-to-capture-current-view-screenshot-and-reuse-in-code-iphone-sdk)) then use the Gaussian blur routines from this library: http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

So, yes it's possible, but not super easy.  You can find similar questions here that will probably help: [stackoverflow.com/search?q=[iphone]+blur](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D+blur)

Comment: Thanks, interesting. And what if things move behind ?

Comment: @ingham, no idea. You will probably need to look deeper into coregraphics and I'm not sure it's possible or worth it.  Perhaps you should update your answer to indicate that that is a requirement (add it in the title) and maybe you'll get more specific responses.

Comment: If you're going to have things moving around and you're planning on using Quartz for example, I'd say that the framerate of the resulting animation would be pretty terrible because of the complexity of the blur routines.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this library:

https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-realtimeblur