# How to take a screenshot from the camera view?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Capture “screenshot” of camera controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996611/ios-capture-screenshot-of-camera-controller)

I'm trying to take a screenshot when the camera of the iphone is running, I want to do this because my goal is to take a lot of screenshot and send them to a server with POST methods to simulate a streaming.
I tried a lot of methods but every time I get a blank image.

I'm french so I'm sorry if my english is bad, and thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You mean that you want to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

add transparant UIView on camera view through overlaying.and then take screenshot from that view.pls check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879064/how-to-capture-current-view-screenshot-and-reuse-in-code-iphone-sdk)